# Which techniques can achieve neural doodle in real-time?

Tags: research, algorithm, real-time, neural-doodle

Ideally I'd like to watch movie which is deep dreamed in real-time. Most algorithms which I know are too slow or not designed for real-time processing.

For example I'm bored with some movie which I've watched thousands of time and I'd like to add some "dreaming" to it which is real-time filter which takes input frames, then it's processing and enhances the images through artificial neural network to achieve doodled output.

Doesn't have to be exactly [DeepDream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepDream) or hallucinogenic technique (which could be too much to watch for 2h), but with any similar ANN algorithm. I'm more interested into achieving desired real-time use.

What kind of techniques can achieve such efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the algorithms (based on [image synthesis and style transfer](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01768), e.g. [neural-doodle](https://github.com/alexjc/neural-doodle)) haven't been proven to be highly effective in terms of real-time image processing.

However the following studies discusses such algorithms for real-time texture synthesis:

- [Feed-forward Synthesis of Textures and Stylized Images](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03417)

  The approach is to move the computational burden to a learning stage, making trained network ([CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network)) light-weight and compact in order to generate multiple samples of the same texture. This can generate textures as good as comparable to [Gatys~et~al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07376), but significantly faster.
- [Perceptual Losses for Real-Time Style Transfer and Super-Resolution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08155)

  This method uses parallel work which can generate high-quality images by defining and optimizing loss functions based on high-level features extracted from pretrained networks.
- [Precomputed Real-Time Texture Synthesis with Markovian Generative Adversarial Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.04382)

  This uses precomputed feed-forward networks that captures the feature statistics of [Markovian patches](http://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/2008_LNLA_Pecot.pdf) in order to generate outputs of arbitrary dimensions. This can be applied to texture synthesis, style transfer and video stylization.

<sup>Source: Above list suggested on [neural-doodle](https://github.com/alexjc/neural-doodle) project.</sup>